# How to redirect a user that doesn't have access to a reserved page?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an admin panel with the route `/admin`. When I try to join the `/admin` route with a user who is not an admin, it's throwing the following exception:

> Expression "has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')" denied access.

It's okay but I want to redirect if the user does not have the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role. I've tried a few things but without success. Here's my function in `AdminController`:

```
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function adminPageAction()
    {
        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            return $this->render('admin.panel.html.twig/admin.panel.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
```

Comment: Why you should want redirect a user that can't access a reserved page? An unauthorized user should not even know that this page exists, and what a bad user experience if you redirect him without giving any info about the "Why". The first downside of this solution is that if you really want this behavior you will have to put the same code in any controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the annotation above. There is no need to put the @Security.